# New GPU causing Linux Mint to not boot

Tags: linux-mint, boot, bios, gpu

I recently got a nice new GPU, but when I have it installed my Linux distro will not boot. I can get to GRUB, but then the system hangs after I select the boot target.

The old GPU I had was an Nvidia EVGA GTX 550 TI, and I upgraded to an AMD XFX Radeon RX 580. When I removed the Nvidia and replaced it with the AMD, I had no video. I installed them both (my motherboard has 2 PCI-E slots) and I can still get video from the Nvidia card, but the OS won't boot. It just hangs after I make a selection in the GRUB menu. If I leave the AMD GPU in the PCI-E slot but remove the connection to the PSU, it will boot and work fine. It only stops booting when I have the AMD GPU connected to the PSU as well as the Motherboard

Other details:

The PSU is 750 watts, so it is plenty to power the new GPU: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B017HA3RGE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017HA3RGE)

The Motherboard is pretty new: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01NCWF5M4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01NCWF5M4)

Here is the output of dmidecode:

```
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0 present.
85 structures occupying 4152 bytes.
Table at 0xCF6CA000.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: F8
    Release Date: 11/08/2017
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 8192 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 5.12

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    Product Name: B250-HD3
    Version: Default string
    Serial Number: Default string
    UUID: 03D502E0-045E-0565-D106-0F0700080009
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: Default string
    Family: Default string

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    Product Name: B250-HD3-CF
    Version: x.x
    Serial Number: Default string
    Asset Tag: Default string
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Default string
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 22 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: Default string
    Type: Desktop
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: Default string
    Serial Number: Default string
    Asset Tag: Default string
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
    Security Status: None
    OEM Information: 0x00000000
    Height: Unspecified
    Number Of Power Cords: 1
    Contained Elements: 0
    SKU Number: Default string

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: PS2Mouse
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Mouse Port

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Keyboard
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Keyboard Port

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: TV Out
    External Connector Type: Mini Centronics Type-14
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A2A
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: COM A
    External Connector Type: DB-9 male
    Port Type: Serial Port 16550A Compatible

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A2B
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Video
    External Connector Type: DB-15 female
    Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB1
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB2
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB3
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9A1 - TPM HDR
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9C1 - PCIE DOCKING CONN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2B3 - CPU FAN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J6C2 - EXT HDMI
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3C1 - GMCH FAN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1D1 - ITP
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9E2 - MDC INTPSR
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9E4 - MDC INTPSR
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9E3 - LPC HOT DOCKING
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9E1 - SCAN MATRIX
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9G1 - LPC SIDE BAND
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J8F1 - UNIFIED
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J6F1 - LVDS
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2F1 - LAI FAN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2G1 - GFX VID
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1G6 - AC JACK
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001C, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J6B2
    Type: x16 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Long
    ID: 0
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:01.0

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J6B1
    Type: x1 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 1
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.3

Handle 0x001E, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J6D1
    Type: x1 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 2
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.4

Handle 0x001F, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J7B1
    Type: x1 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 3
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.5

Handle 0x0020, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J8B4
    Type: x1 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 4
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.6

Handle 0x0021, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Description:    To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x0022, DMI type 11, 5 bytes
OEM Strings
    String 1: Default string

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options
    Option 1: Default string

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 34, 11 bytes
Management Device
    Description: LM78-1
    Type: LM78
    Address: 0x00000000
    Address Type: I/O Port

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 26, 22 bytes
Voltage Probe
    Description: LM78A
    Location: Motherboard
    Status: OK
    Maximum Value: Unknown
    Minimum Value: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
    Tolerance: Unknown
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Value: Unknown

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 36, 16 bytes
Management Device Threshold Data
    Lower Non-critical Threshold: 1
    Upper Non-critical Threshold: 2
    Lower Critical Threshold: 3
    Upper Critical Threshold: 4
    Lower Non-recoverable Threshold: 5
    Upper Non-recoverable Threshold: 6

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 35, 11 bytes
Management Device Component
    Description: Default string
    Management Device Handle: 0x0025
    Component Handle: 0x0026
    Threshold Handle: 0x0027

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 28, 22 bytes
Temperature Probe
    Description: LM78A
    Location: Motherboard
    Status: OK
    Maximum Value: Unknown
    Minimum Value: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
    Tolerance: Unknown
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Value: Unknown

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 36, 16 bytes
Management Device Threshold Data
    Lower Non-critical Threshold: 1
    Upper Non-critical Threshold: 2
    Lower Critical Threshold: 3
    Upper Critical Threshold: 4
    Lower Non-recoverable Threshold: 5
    Upper Non-recoverable Threshold: 6

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 35, 11 bytes
Management Device Component
    Description: Default string
    Management Device Handle: 0x0025
    Component Handle: 0x0029
    Threshold Handle: 0x002A

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 27, 15 bytes
Cooling Device
    Temperature Probe Handle: 0x0029
    Type: Power Supply Fan
    Status: OK
    Cooling Unit Group: 1
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Speed: Unknown Or Non-rotating
    Description: Cooling Dev 1

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 36, 16 bytes
Management Device Threshold Data
    Lower Non-critical Threshold: 1
    Upper Non-critical Threshold: 2
    Lower Critical Threshold: 3
    Upper Critical Threshold: 4
    Lower Non-recoverable Threshold: 5
    Upper Non-recoverable Threshold: 6

Handle 0x002E, DMI type 35, 11 bytes
Management Device Component
    Description: Default string
    Management Device Handle: 0x0025
    Component Handle: 0x002C
    Threshold Handle: 0x002D

Handle 0x002F, DMI type 27, 15 bytes
Cooling Device
    Temperature Probe Handle: 0x0029
    Type: Power Supply Fan
    Status: OK
    Cooling Unit Group: 1
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Speed: Unknown Or Non-rotating
    Description: Not Specified

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 36, 16 bytes
Management Device Threshold Data
    Lower Non-critical Threshold: 1
    Upper Non-critical Threshold: 2
    Lower Critical Threshold: 3
    Upper Critical Threshold: 4
    Lower Non-recoverable Threshold: 5
    Upper Non-recoverable Threshold: 6

Handle 0x0031, DMI type 35, 11 bytes
Management Device Component
    Description: Default string
    Management Device Handle: 0x0025
    Component Handle: 0x002F
    Threshold Handle: 0x0030

Handle 0x0032, DMI type 29, 22 bytes
Electrical Current Probe
    Description: ABC
    Location: Motherboard
    Status: OK
    Maximum Value: Unknown
    Minimum Value: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
    Tolerance: Unknown
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Value: Unknown

Handle 0x0033, DMI type 36, 16 bytes
Management Device Threshold Data

Handle 0x0034, DMI type 35, 11 bytes
Management Device Component
    Description: Default string
    Management Device Handle: 0x0025
    Component Handle: 0x0032
    Threshold Handle: 0x0033

Handle 0x0035, DMI type 26, 22 bytes
Voltage Probe
    Description: LM78A
    Location: Power Unit
    Status: OK
    Maximum Value: Unknown
    Minimum Value: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
    Tolerance: Unknown
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Value: Unknown

Handle 0x0036, DMI type 28, 22 bytes
Temperature Probe
    Description: LM78A
    Location: Power Unit
    Status: OK
    Maximum Value: Unknown
    Minimum Value: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
    Tolerance: Unknown
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Value: Unknown

Handle 0x0037, DMI type 27, 15 bytes
Cooling Device
    Temperature Probe Handle: 0x0036
    Type: Power Supply Fan
    Status: OK
    Cooling Unit Group: 1
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Speed: Unknown Or Non-rotating
    Description: Cooling Dev 1

Handle 0x0038, DMI type 29, 22 bytes
Electrical Current Probe
    Description: ABC
    Location: Power Unit
    Status: OK
    Maximum Value: Unknown
    Minimum Value: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
    Tolerance: Unknown
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Value: Unknown

Handle 0x0039, DMI type 39, 22 bytes
System Power Supply
    Power Unit Group: 1
    Location: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Name: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Model Part Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Revision: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Max Power Capacity: Unknown
    Status: Present, OK
    Type: Switching
    Input Voltage Range Switching: Auto-switch
    Plugged: Yes
    Hot Replaceable: No
    Input Voltage Probe Handle: 0x0035
    Cooling Device Handle: 0x0037
    Input Current Probe Handle: 0x0038

Handle 0x003A, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation:  Onboard IGD
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:00:02.0

Handle 0x003B, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation:  Onboard LAN
    Type: Ethernet
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:00:19.0

Handle 0x003C, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation:  Onboard 1394
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:03:1c.2

Handle 0x003D, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 64 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x003E, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x003D
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2133 MHz
    Manufacturer: 8502
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: 2133 C14 Series     
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x003F, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x003D
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: Unknown
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown

Handle 0x0040, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x003D
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: Unknown
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown

Handle 0x0042, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x003D
    Partition Width: 1

Handle 0x0043, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 128 kB
    Maximum Size: 128 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Parity
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0044, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L2 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 512 kB
    Maximum Size: 512 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 4-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0045, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L3 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 3
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 3072 kB
    Maximum Size: 3072 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 12-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0046, DMI type 4, 48 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: U3E1
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Core i3
    Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
    ID: E9 06 09 00 FF FB EB BF
    Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 158, Stepping 9
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        DS (Debug store)
        ACPI (ACPI supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        SS (Self-snoop)
        HTT (Multi-threading)
        TM (Thermal monitor supported)
        PBE (Pending break enabled)
    Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-7100 CPU @ 3.90GHz
    Voltage: 1.1 V
    External Clock: 100 MHz
    Max Speed: 8300 MHz
    Current Speed: 3900 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: Other
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0043
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0044
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x0045
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Part Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Core Count: 2
    Core Enabled: 2
    Thread Count: 4
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable
        Multi-Core
        Hardware Thread
        Execute Protection
        Enhanced Virtualization
        Power/Performance Control

Handle 0x0047, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x003E
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0042
    Partition Row Position: Unknown

Handle 0x0048, DMI type 130, 20 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        82 14 48 00 24 41 4D 54 00 00 00 00 00 A5 AF 02
        C0 00 00 00

Handle 0x0049, DMI type 131, 64 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        83 40 49 00 31 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
        F8 00 C8 A2 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 08 00 0B 00
        47 0D 32 00 00 00 00 00 FE 00 B8 15 00 00 00 00
        00 00 00 00 22 00 00 00 76 50 72 6F 00 00 00 00

Handle 0x004A, DMI type 221, 26 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        DD 1A 4A 00 03 01 00 01 03 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
        00 5E 00 03 00 00 05 00 00 00
    Strings:
        Reference Code - CPU
        uCode Version
        TXT ACM version

Handle 0x004B, DMI type 221, 26 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        DD 1A 4B 00 03 01 00 01 03 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
        00 00 00 03 04 0B 08 32 47 0D
    Strings:
        Reference Code - ME 11.0
        MEBx version
        ME Firmware Version
        Consumer SKU

Handle 0x004C, DMI type 221, 75 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        DD 4B 4C 00 0A 01 00 01 03 00 00 00 02 03 FF FF
        FF FF FF 04 00 FF FF FF 00 00 05 00 FF FF FF 00
        00 06 00 FF FF FF FF FF 07 00 3E 00 00 00 00 08
        00 34 00 00 00 00 09 00 0B 00 00 00 00 0A 00 3E
        00 00 00 00 0B 00 34 00 00 00 00
    Strings:
        Reference Code - SKL PCH
        PCH-CRID Status
        Disabled
        PCH-CRID Original Value
        PCH-CRID New Value
        OPROM - RST - RAID
        SKL PCH H Bx Hsio Version
        SKL PCH H Dx Hsio Version
        KBL PCH H Ax Hsio Version
        SKL PCH LP Bx Hsio Version
        SKL PCH LP Cx Hsio Version

Handle 0x004D, DMI type 221, 54 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        DD 36 4D 00 07 01 00 01 03 00 00 00 02 00 01 03
        00 00 00 03 00 01 03 00 00 00 04 05 FF FF FF FF
        FF 06 00 FF FF FF 06 00 07 00 FF FF FF 06 00 08
        00 FF FF FF 02 03
    Strings:
        Reference Code - SA - System Agent
        Reference Code - MRC
        SA - PCIe Version
        SA-CRID Status
        Disabled
        SA-CRID Original Value
        SA-CRID New Value
        OPROM - VBIOS

Handle 0x004E, DMI type 221, 103 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        DD 67 4E 00 0E 01 00 00 00 00 A6 00 02 00 FF FF
        FF FF FF 03 04 FF FF FF FF FF 05 06 FF FF FF FF
        FF 07 08 FF FF FF FF FF 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A
        00 FF FF FF FF FF 0B 00 FF FF 00 00 00 0C 00 FF
        FF FF FF FF 0D 00 02 00 00 00 00 0E 00 FF FF FF
        FF FF 0F 00 FF FF FF FF FF 10 11 01 03 03 01 00
        12 00 00 07 03 00 00
    Strings:
        Lan Phy Version
        Sensor Firmware Version
        Debug Mode Status
        Disabled
        Performance Mode Status
        Disabled
        Debug Use USB(Disabled:Serial)
        Disabled
        ICC Overclocking Version
        UNDI Version
        EC FW Version
        GOP Version
        BIOS Guard Version
        Base EC FW Version
        EC-EC Protocol Version
        Royal Park Version
        BP1.3.3.0_RP01
        Platform Version

Handle 0x004F, DMI type 136, 6 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        88 06 4F 00 00 00

Handle 0x0050, DMI type 14, 20 bytes
Group Associations
    Name: Firmware Version Info
    Items: 5
        0x004A (<OUT OF SPEC>)
        0x004B (<OUT OF SPEC>)
        0x004C (<OUT OF SPEC>)
        0x004D (<OUT OF SPEC>)
        0x004E (<OUT OF SPEC>)

Handle 0x0052, DMI type 14, 8 bytes
Group Associations
    Name: $MEI
    Items: 1
        0x0000 (<OUT OF SPEC>)

Handle 0x0053, DMI type 219, 81 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        DB 51 53 00 01 03 01 55 02 00 90 06 03 10 81 20
        00 00 00 04 40 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02
        FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
        FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 03 00 00 00 80 00 00 00
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
        00
    Strings:
        MEI1
        MEI2
        MEI3

Handle 0x0054, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```

(I omitted a couple things to make it under the character limit for a post)

Is this perhaps a BIOS issue? Do I likely have a dead GPU?

Comment: Likely your PSU cannot handle both cards inserted. 750Wt can be misleading. Start by burining a live CD/DVD with your favourite flavour of Linux and booting from it with the new video card inserted only. If it works, you are better off reinstalling the OS from scratch, all other options may be too time consuming considering you do not even have a running OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the old competing brand names in the one system issue.
Linux is not as forgiving as windows in SOME things, and VGA drivers are one of the biggies.
Your PSU seems good enough, its not a SHAW or some other "cheap" kit. It looks like a driver issue (well, lets TRY correcting that first.)

boot into linux using the nvidia.
remove ALL nvidia drivers.
remove using command one or both of the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

or

```
sudo apt-get autoremove nvidia-* --purge
```

YOU MAY BE ABLE TO SHUTDOWN NOW, and REMOVE THE NVIDIA AND BOOT TO THE AMD.  If fail do the next bits.
...If you installed the driver yourself, manually, then find or re-download that installer file. Then put it in your home folder, open a terminal and type (you can simply open the terminal in that folder, and run the following without the ~/ bit if you want)

```
sudo ~/installation_of_nvidia_file.run --uninstall
```

if that poops itself, try the ./ way, from a terminal open in the same directory as the install file:

```
./installation_of_nvidia_file.run --uninstall
```

you may then have to add this, it refreshes stuff I think (kernel source):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source linux-headers-generic linux-image
```

OK....so the UNINSTALL and PURGE has succeeded, youve have SHUTDOWN the PC, and you have UNPLUGGED the nVidia card.  Now connect the AMD and boot.
The AMD stuff should work out of the box.
If you really want to use AMD drivers, it's apparently tricky on Mint, try this:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=248059

Mint 17 and 18 AMDGPU drivers! Look here before doing anything!
HINT:

```
nano amdgpu-pro-install
```

Scroll down until you see "ubuntu" listed below a section "function os_release". Where it says "**ubuntu**", delete that and make it "**linuxmint**". (Do not change anything else but "ubuntu" to "linuxmint"!!)
Hit "CTRL+o" to save, "Enter" to confirm, then "CTRL+x" to exit. Keep the terminal open.

8 ) Install the AMD driver.

```
./amdgpu-pro-install -y
```

crack a beer and thank the internets!